# Why is there a non-functional dropdown menu in the top bar while viewing users' network profiles?

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, network-profile

Within the last hour or so, I've noticed that, when viewing a user's network profile, there is an additional icon in the top bar:

[image: The top bar icons on the network profile page, The new icon on the far-right is highlighted with a red freehand circle.]

It looks like it's intended to be some sort of dropdown menu, but nothing actually happens when you click on it.

**What is it?** I assume it's an unfinished feature that accidentally got deployed before it was ready?

Comment: I figured someone must have asked about this already but didn't realise it would so far down the questions list, my bad.