# Person icon with drop down symbol in the stackexchange.com top bar

Tags: support, top-bar, stackexchange.com, icons

There is an person icon with a drop down symbol in the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) header (top bar). Clicking on that doesn't respond any.

What is the icon for?

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The new icon on the topbar on stackexchange.com doesn't have a dropdown menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378713/the-new-icon-on-the-topbar-on-stackexchange-com-doesnt-have-a-dropdown-menu) . Note this was also asked about more recently at [Why is there a non-functional dropdown menu in the top bar while viewing users' network profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378739/562482).

Comment: I am glad I looked at the questions, or I would have asked another duplicate.

Comment: @apaderno yeah, well, that's a pretty glaring bug, lots of people see it so it's no wonder we get many duplicates.